# Drupal 9 Login page missing (logged out and can not login)

Tags: authentication, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-9

I was trying to set path for login page as /user/login but login form was not showing up, now by mistake I have logged out and cannot login. Please help me in logging in.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VigcC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably override the template for this page.
Use the twig debug and look out the template.
Without more informations it's the only thing that I can say.

How did you override the login path?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drush you can use uli command https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:login/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have overridden the template as suggested by Sharklalu

Alternatively, you can place the user block on the page to display the form.